# Adding item to listview between an Activity and a Fragment

Tags: android

Hi guys I'm building an IRC client, its like a chat app. I have a fragment called Channel that has a list view of channels. Each time I click on a channel, the SingleChannalActivity is showed. Inside that I can type /join #channel to join a channel, and I want to add that channel to the list view in the previous Fragment. But I keep getting nullpointerexception saying that my listview is null.

Whenever I type /join, the addChannel method is called, but the listview is null.

**ChannelFragment**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_channel, container, false);

    channelList = new ArrayList<>();

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        nick = bundle.getString("nick");
        channel = bundle.getString("channel");
    }

    channelListView = v.findViewById(R.id.channelListView);

    channelList.add(new Channel(channel, "0 people"));

    adapter = new ChannelListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.adapter_view_channel_layout, channelList);
    channelListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    channelListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),SingleChannelActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    return v;
}

public void addChannel(String channel) {
    channelList.add(new Channel(channel, "0 people"));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**addChannel method in SingleChannelActivity**

```
public void join(String channel) {
    if (!channel.isEmpty()) {
        connection.send("JOIN " + channel);

        ChannelFragment channelFragment = new ChannelFragment();
        channelFragment.addChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

It keeps saying my channelList.add line is null meaning I dont have a channelList at the time I type /join. Can you guys tell me the problem?

**Log cat**

```
2019-12-21 23:41:32.197 19744-19744/com.example.ircclient E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ircclient, PID: 19744
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.ircclient.Channels.ChannelFragment.addChannel(ChannelFragment.java:87)
    at com.example.ircclient.Channels.SingleChannelActivity.join(SingleChannelActivity.java:144)
    at com.example.ircclient.Channels.SingleChannelActivity.parseIn(SingleChannelActivity.java:109)
    at com.example.ircclient.Channels.SingleChannelActivity.access$100(SingleChannelActivity.java:29)
    at com.example.ircclient.Channels.SingleChannelActivity$1.onClick(SingleChannelActivity.java:81)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12693)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26101)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

How do I communicate between 1 fragment and 1 activity? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really doing here is not a feasible approach to send data between activity and fragment.Creating an object of a fragment and access a method using it and also send a string  as a parameter is impossible to receive by fragment from activity.Thats why when you try to add Chanel in your fragment `public void addChannel(String channel)` method it gives null point exception because it never received any.Use bundles to send data from activity to fragment.When you receive it from activity to your fragment receive it in `onViewCreated` method,then add it to your list.Let initialize your view only in `onCreateView` and set others  in `onViewCreated`.try like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_channel, container, false);

return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    channelListView = v.findViewById(R.id.channelListView);
    channelList = new ArrayList<>();//declare it in class level


     Bundle bundle = getArguments();
     if (bundle != null) {
     nick = bundle.getString("nick");
    channel = bundle.getString("channel");
    }
     channelList.add(new Channel(channel, "0 people"));           

adapter = new ChannelListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.adapter_view_channel_layout, channelList);
channelListView.setAdapter(adapter);

channelListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),SingleChannelActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Yes I rewrote my code like yours. Basically I want to add an item to the channelList created in the fragment, and calling the addChannel from the activity. But it keeps telling me Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object), which means my channelList is not created? :( Thanks

Comment: can you post your logcat here?

Comment: `channelList = new ArrayList<>();` initialize it in class level like `ArrayList<Channel> channelList=new ArrayList<>();

Comment: I did, I initialized it globally like that

Comment: post your MainActivity plz

Comment: yes it seems like it works if I initialize it globally hehe. Thank you!